# [C]add, edit, delete data with struct and file

Tags: c, file, structure

I do not know if I'm writing the code correctly, my intent is' to have written somewhere of the "singers" with their characteristics (name, surname, id, genre, etc. ..), I would like to display them on screen and in a menu switch choose whether to add, edit, or delete one of them based on the user's choice (only I have an array of 21 and I do not know how to add more later ..) In Case 1 I write that structure on file, in 2 houses I visualize them on screen. If you can help me I would be grateful, it's days I can not find a solution., I accept any constructive advice

```
            #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    //costanti
    #define maxnomeau 16
    #define maxcognomeau 18
    #define maxnazionalitaau 14
    #define maxmusicaau 12
    #define maxvet 21


    //definisco la struttura autore
    typedef struct {

    int id;
    char nome[maxnomeau];
    char cognome[maxcognomeau];
    char nazionalita[maxnazionalitau];
    char sesso[2];
    char musica[maxmusicaau];

    }autori;



    int main(void)
    {

    autori vettaut[maxvet]={

            {1,"Bob", "Sinclair","Francese","M","House"},
            {2,"Michael", "Jackson","Americana","M","Pop"},
            {3,"Loredana", "Berte'","Italiana","F","Rock"},
            {4,"Albano", "Carrisi","Italiana","M","Leggera"},
            {5,"Tim", "Bergling","Svedese","M","House"},
            {6,"Tiziano", "Ferro","Italiana","M","Pop"},
            {7,"Fabrizio", "Tarducci","Italiana","M","Rap"},
            {8,"David", "Guetta","Francese","M","Elettronica"},
            {9,"Sfera", "Ebbasta","Italiana","M","Trap"},
            {10,"Gue'", "Pequeno","Italiana","M","Rap"},
            {11,"Vittorio", "Dimango","Italiana","M","House"},
            {12,"Taylor","Swift","Americana","F","Pop"},
            {13,"Antonello", "Venditti","Italiana","M","Leggera"},
            {14,"Fabrizio", "Deandre'","Italiana","M","Leggera"},
            {15,"Capo", "Plaza","Italiana","M","Trap"},
            {16,"Dark", "Pologang","Italiana","M","Trap"},
            {17,"Sonny", "Skrillex","Americano","M","Elettronica"},
            {18,"Beatrice", "Antolini","Italiana","F","Elettronica"},
            {19,"Fabio", "Marracash","Italiana","M","Rap"},
            {20,"Roger", "Waters","Inglese","M","Rock"},
            {21,"Jimi", "Hendrix","Inglese","M","Rock"}
            };

      case 1: //la scelta 1 e' la scrittura dei cantanti su file
    {system("cls");


    FILE *fp;

    fp=fopen("autori.dat","w");
    if(fp==NULL)
    {
         printf("errore\n");
    }
    else
    for(i=0;i<maxvet;i++)
    {
    fprintf(fp,"\n\n %d \t %s \t %s \t %s \t %s \t %s\n",vettaut[i].id,vettaut[i].nome,vettaut[i].cognome,vettaut[i].nazionalita,vettaut[i].sesso,vettaut           [i].musica);


    }
    fclose(fp);
    printf("Gli artisti sono stati salvati sul file <autori.dat>\n");

            system("pause");
            system("cls");
            }
            break;

        case 2: //la scelta 2 e' la visualizzazione su schermo di tutti i cantanti
            {system("cls");
                FILE *fp;
    if((fp=fopen("autori.dat","r"))==NULL) {
         printf("Errore Visualizzazione\n");
    }
    else
    printf("%-4s || %-12s || %-12s || %-12s || %-2s || %-12s || \n\n","<ID>","<NOME>","<COGNOME","NAZIONALITA'","<SESSO>","<MUSICA>");
    for(i=0;i<maxvet;i++)
    {
    fscanf(fp,"%d %s %s %s %s %s",&vettaut[i].id,vettaut[i].nome,vettaut[i].cognome,vettaut[i].nazionalita,vettaut[i].sesso,vettaut[i].musica);
    printf("%-4d || %-12s || %-12s || %-12s || %-7s || %-12s || \n\n",vettaut[i].id,vettaut[i].nome,vettaut[i].cognome,vettaut[i].nazionalita,vettaut           [i].sesso,vettaut[i].musica);

    }
    fclose(fp);



            system("pause");
            system("cls");}
            break;
```

Comment: Does the code work? Please state a clear problem.

Comment: Aside: your different string lengths in `autori` are oddly picky. It would be better to define the members as `char *` pointers, since you have hard coded the data. Except the `char sesso[2];` which can only hold a string length of `1` so there is little point. You say you want to add and edit, so that puts another dimension. No attempt was shown, but, there are many similar examples out there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allocate a variable amount of elements in a list, use `malloc` or `realloc` in `stdlib.h`. In Linux, look at `man 3 malloc` which will bring up the manual pages for it.